# How to create and display a custom base map with ESRI Leaflet?

Tags: esri-leaflet, esri-oss

The educational web app I'm working on makes use of ESRI base maps displayed with Leaflet. (See [CODAP](http://codap.concord.org/releases/latest/) and click the Map tool.) One of our partners would like to be able to use a base map that displays biomes as, for example, displayed [here](http://w3.marietta.edu/~biol/biomes/biomemap.htm).

ESRI supplies a bunch of useful base maps. But how do I create my own? And can I start with an image like the one linked to above?

Answer (score -1):

typically people use either ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro to publish their own content as services hosted either on ArcGIS Online or their own installation of ArcGIS Server, but its also possible to upload shapefiles, csvs and other files into [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com) directly using the website.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/use-hosted-layers.htm

anyone can get a perpetual free account for R&D and non-commercial service hosting by signing up on our Developers website.

https://developers.arcgis.com